# or-tools: set a timeout for SCIP solver

Tags: or-tools, scip, cp-sat

The or-tools Python package does not describe how to set the timeout for a mixed integer programming SCIP solver.

The [method](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_tasks) for the CP-SAT solver does not exist for SCIP solver.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at source code, the appropriate method is

`solver.set_time_limit(10_000)`